# customer list IN and NOT IN

Tags: sql

how to get a customer number who fell under a category till 7/31 but did not on 8/1?

```
select customer_number
from table 
where
purchased = 'a'
and date = '07-31-2020'
```

Assume I have data till 8/31/2020.

I want to get the list of customer numbers who purchased 'a' till 7/31 but did not purchase after that

Comment: Normally you'll want [ISO 8601 dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), as in `YYYY-MM-DD`, if only so these can be sorted.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Do you want the customer if the last purchase is on 2020-07-30?  What if the customer purchased something different after your date?  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below -

```
select customer_number 
from table where purchased = 'a' 
group by customer_number
having max(date)='07-31-2020'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

There is an another variant.
how to get a customer number who fell under a category till 8/1 but not on 8/31?

Comment: @user14263992 did it help u?

Comment: will this be a right logic for the variant?

select customer_number 
from table where purchased = 'a' 
group by customer_number
having max(date)='08-1-2020'

Comment: @user14263992, yes it seems so

Comment: Based on your logic *who purchased 'a' till 7/31* it should be `having max(date) <= date '2020-07-31'`

Answer (score 2):

I would use a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where purchased = 'a'
and not exists (select *
                from the_table t2
                where t2.customer_number = t1.customer_number
                  and t2.date > date '2020-07-31');
```